# How to make a facebook sign-up feature in ios app?

Tags: ios, facebook

I have a issue to make a facebook sign-up feature in ios app. I have read many samples such as facebook_ios_sdk v1.1. There is only a log-in button in them. But I want a sign-up feature, too. Help me to make it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware, the API does not provide support for sign-up. 
However, the login web view has a link for registering, which will take you to Safari and allow you to go through the registration process.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. Could you show me a way to return back home screen from ios safari after logging in facebook?