# Sign Up with Facebook in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

According to the [facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/features/ios6-sdk-integration/), there is a way to `Sign In` with Facebook in your iOS app, however, is there any way to `Sign Up` with their API ? Thanx in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633484/how-to-make-a-facebook-sign-up-feature-in-ios-app.

Comment: Yes, it's around the same topic, but i need an updated answer, maybe Facebook launched a SignUp service meanwhile. Can you confirm? Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround might be using the Windows Azure for iOS Framwork: http://bit.ly/PAwAGx

But I havn't used it yet, just read about it.